# Orphan section headers (using customized sections)

Tags: sectioning

I am writing my research proposal using a custom `thesis.sty`(actual file name is different) file provided by my university. The section headers generated using this style file break at the end of the page. So there are orphan section headers at the page end. In one instance there is a page break within the section header itself, in this case the section header was longer than one line. Here is a snippet of the `thesis.sty` file that defines custom section and subsections:

```
%==============================================================
% BEGIN Section and subsection Customization 
%==============================================================

%\def\section#1{\ifnum\chaptertest>1 \vskip 0.25in \else \vskip 0.01in \fi
 \def\section#1{\ifnum\chaptertest>1 \vskip 0.25in \else \vskip 0.25in \fi
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \refstepcounter{section}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect
        \numberline{\thesection.}#1}\else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}\fi
    \sectionmark{#1}
    \noindent %T
    %T \centerline{$\underline{\hbox{\thesection.} _{\ } \ \hbox{#1}}$}
    \Null {\bf \thesection. \ #1}%T Removed preceeding space before bf which makes headers misaligned TCM
    \vskip -0.23in %% Ju
    \indent
}

%\def\sectiondl#1#2{\ifnum\chaptertest>1 \vskip 0.25in \else \vskip 0.01in \fi
 \def\sectiondl#1#2{\ifnum\chaptertest>1 \vskip 0.25in \else \vskip 0.25in \fi
                \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
 \refstepcounter{section}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect
 \numberline{\thesection.}#1 #2}\else
 \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1 #2}\fi
 \sectionmark{#1 #2}

 \centerline{$\underline{\hbox{\thesection.} _{\ } \ \hbox{#1}}$}
 \centerline{$\underline{\hbox{\thesection.} _{\ } \ \hbox{#1}}$}
 \centerline{$\underline{_{\ } \hbox{#2}}$}
 \vskip -0.09in %% Ju
 \indent
 }

 \def\subsection#1{\vskip 0.25in \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
 \refstepcounter{subsection}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect
 \numberline{\thesubsection.}#1}\else
 \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}\fi
 \subsectionmark{#1}
%T \centerline{\thesubsection. \ #1}
 \noindent %T
 \Null \thesubsection. \ #1
  \vskip -0.27in  %% Ju: space betw. name to the fisrt line
 \indent

 }

 \def\subsectiondl#1#2{\vskip 0.25in \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
 \refstepcounter{subsection}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect
 \numberline{\thesubsection.}#1 #2}\else
 \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1 #2}\fi
 \subsectionmark{#1}


 }

 \def\subsubsection#1{\vskip 0.25in \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
 \refstepcounter{subsubsection}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\protect
 \numberline{\thesubsubsection.}#1}\else
 \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{#1}\fi
 \subsubsectionmark{#1}
 \noindent
 %\centerline{\thesubsubsection. \ #1}  %% title is on the middle originally
 %T\Null \thesubsubsection. \ #1  %% Ju move it to the left ( standard requirement)
 \Null {\em \thesubsubsection. \ #1 } %% Ju move it to the left ( standard requirement) % Removed preceeding space before em which makes headers misaligned TCM
                                %T \Null added to show first numeral
 \vskip -0.27in
 \indent

 }

 \def\subsubsectiondl#1#2{\vskip 0.25in \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
 \refstepcounter{subsubsection}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\protect
 \numberline{\thesubsubsection.}#1 #2}\else
 \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{#1 #2}\fi
 \subsubsectionmark{#1 #2}
 \noindent
 \centerline{\em \thesubsubsection. \ #1} \vskip -0.08in
 \centerline{\em #2}
 \vskip -0.27in
 \indent
 }

%==============================================================
% END Section and subsection Customization 
%==============================================================
```

This is how the sections headers should look using the thesis.sty format that I have to use:

[image: Section headers generated using the custom thesis.sty format]

I am also providing this additional bit of detail just in case if it gives any clues to solve this problem. Quite weirdly, the way this thesis.sty is designed, we are supposed to add one blank line after the section label else it causes problems with the spacing between the header and the following paragraph.

```
\section{section header}
<leave a blank line>
Start Paragraph from here.
```

However, it does not bother me that I have to add a blank line after section labels. Its a minor inconvenience that I will look into later. For now I really don't know to fix those orphan section headers. I looked at a lot of threads on here regarding the same problem but none of those solutions work for me. Please let me know if I need to provide any additional information to help troubleshoot this. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Welcome! If you really *have* to use `thesis.sty`, then presumably you are stuck with the style. If you just mean you *are* using it because it is *supposed* to make life easier, don't use it. It won't make life easier. If that excerpt is straight for the `.sty` and really hasn't been messed up in your reproducing it here, don't walk away. Run.

Comment: LaTeX has an interface that is used for all internal section like commands. Commands defined by that interface prohibit orphans. Your style file just gives a **** and redefines those commands without taking care of prohibiting orphans.

Comment: By the way, check the copyright and license of the package file. You might not even be allowed to redistribute parts of it (under a free license). It might be better to just share a link. Or maybe your university is still maintaining the package (which they should, else this is just a file with useless text in it) and can help you out and fix the style for other users as well?

Comment: the code isn't really fixable just from that fragment, it is almost all wrong, it does not use any of the mechanisms latex has for section headings, it omits `%` from lots of lines so will add spurious white space in many instances, it fails as you note, to correctly handle paragraph breaking, the combination of negative vskip and `\indent`  means that you must _never_ leave a blank line after the heading, if you do then not only is the spacing poor you will always have a spurious paragraph with no text after the heading.

Comment: @cfr I am supposed to use the format that this `thesis.sty` has laid out. Generating the entire format by myself might be a lot of work, and this `.sty` is a mess.

Comment: @Johannes_B The package is publicly accessible on the website. I see no copyright notice, but I will double check. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are right. Is there any way I can generate sections headers like the way I have it in the screenshot ? But at the same time also make it work with the rest of the `thesis.sty` such the section numbers, entry into the table of contents and everything else works out ?

Comment: Easiest would be, honestly, not to use the package. Have a ook at [writing a scientific report with LaTeX](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports).

Comment: Can you add a link to the question where we can find the template/package?

Comment: @Johannes_B I was hoping that it wouldn't come to this. My university follows a specific format (margins, spacing, fonts and a lot of other such details).

I am updating the question with the link to the package. Thanks!

Comment: To be a bit frank, blunt and rude: The complete code posted is just rubbish. There is no reason for anybody, not a helper, nor you, to get hands on trying to make the code better. Current LaTeX is stable for almost 25 years now, the internals work fine. Why build pure strangeness on top?

Comment: @Johannes_B I understand. I personally wouldn't have used it either if I had any other option. Guess I will have to figure out a cleaner way to get the formatting right. 

I see that there is a copyright notice but since the file is publicly available, I don't know what difference it would make. Apparently it was first written a long time back (1989) and since then it was tweaked several times and now it's a bigger mess.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is often the case with thesis templates. They have a ong history and once in a while a guy comes by and adds stuff. Looking at the example pdf, i don't see anything very strange. Centered chapter titles, UPPERCASE titles and double line spacing and incostitent spacing and indentation. That is normal for american universities.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to spend a weekend and try to make my own `.sty` file. I will just learn more in the process (though I certainly would have loved to save that time). I am glad that this forum exists so I can ask more questions later. Thanks !!

Comment: there doesn't seem anything special about the headings in your image, just uppercase and followed by indent, which you could do in  two lines of code, either copying article.cls version and adding \MakeUppercase or using titlesec or one of the other packages for specifying headings

Comment: Would you be happy if we closed this? If you have questions as you work on your `.sty` file (which really shouldn't need to be very complicated, by the sound of it, and will be much easier to help with), it would probably make most sense to ask new questions about those issues.

Comment: @cfr Yes, please close it

Comment: I've voted to close. Note that we have a limited number of 'close reasons', so don't be surprised if the 'because...' bit sounds  not quite accurate!